# Compiling an Angular 1.x project

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I've been handed an Angular 1.5.6 project that has source files and compiled files but nothing to instruct how to compile the source files. Is there a standard approach I'm missing to do this? There's no buildfile, package.json, angular.json file in the src directory.

Comment: Maybe if you provide a directory listing of the base of the project including dot files someone can identify something.  There could be grunt, gulp, webpack or some other tool being used...

Comment: The AngularJS framework self-compiles in the browser after the  `DOMContentLoaded` event. Any minification, bundling, annotation, and transpiling that may have been done would use third-party software and are not part of the standard core AngularJS framework.

Answer (score 0):

Question is quite general. 
Not sure about any 3rd party libs may be present and require some additional transformation, but angular app source files probably may be just be joined altogether(maybe after transpiling with Babel) and injected into HTML  with `<script>` right after `angular.js` itself.

Also if you see something like strange `"ngInject";` strings or comments you will probably need [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate/blob/master/README.md) module to autogenerate dependencies for modules. It may be run in combination with gulp or Babel.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I found an uglify script buried in the project that stitched the source files together.